# Outlook/HTML - How do I get the html content to show rounded rectangle as a uniform circle?

Tags: html, css, outlook

Here is my template code (C#).  I need the v:roundrect (height = 100px) to render as a circle width = height, regardless of width of nested image width.  Ideally I want to dictate the diameter of the circle based in image width.

How do I go about fixing this so that my roundrect looks like a circle and not a wide rectangle with curved edges?

[image: RoudnedRect]

```
                            <!--[if mso]>
                                <v:roundrect xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' style='height:100px; min-height: 100px !important;' arcsize='1000%' stroke='FFD700'>
                                  <w:anchorlock/>
                                    <center>
                                     <img width='40' src='{1}' alt='dot' />
                                   </center>
                                </v:roundrect>
                                <![endif]-->
                             <!--[if !mso]> <!---->
                                <div class='partnerlogo'>
                                    <img width=40' src='{1}' alt='dot' />
                                </div>                        
                            <![endif]-->    
                            &nbsp; 
                        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `<img width=40' src='{1}' alt='dot' />` you are assigning this: `width: 40px;`.

You need it also to have the same `height`. So if you already know that will be `width: 40px` *(like you posted)* then try this in your `CSS`:

```
.partnerlogo img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px; 
}
```

And your code should be this:

```
<div class='partnerlogo'>
     <img src='{1}' alt='dot' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @SrAxi, in MS Outlook, the width='40' is intentional because '40px' is not recognized.  But let me try the solution.  I have had previous issues with css width, so I used width='40' to force the image to be at most 40px.

Comment: Let me know how it goes. If it gets overrided try: `width: 40px!important`. I hope I was useful somehow. I'll wait your feedback! ;) Good Luck! :D

Comment: Thanks @SrAxi, I managed to get a semi circle, more like a rounded rectangle.  But still working on it.